# ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use DRY in React JS. I'm trying to use the same HTML partial in different files

partial:

```
var AdminMenu = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
   return {};
 },
 render: function() {
   return (
     <h1>Menu</h1>
   );
 }
});
```

I'm requeiring it in another file:

```
require('./scripts/adminMenu.js');

ReactDOM.render(
 <AdminMenu/>,
 document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

this scripts are included on html page like:
`<script type="text/babel" src="scripts/admin.js"></script>`

I'm using webpack

Comment: Which packager/builder are you using?

Comment: Your Code looks buggy, you are requiring adminMenu, but you dont assign it.. Why are you not using ES import / export? Have you checked webpack.config.js for React best practices?

Comment: you are also not exporting `AdminMenu` do you know how modules works?

Comment: @webdeb but I'm assigning `AdminMenu` like `var AdminMenu = ...`

Comment: I see, but you are not exporting it

Comment: I think you missed to understand how `require` `import` `modules` works, or am I wrong?

Comment: @webdeb yes, I'm completely beginner at ReactJS

Comment: You just start trying ReactJS, it's normal that things don't work, you should consider to checkout some of the quardramillion examples out there, to learn it properly, however, I answered you question whit an es6 export / import example written with the new es6 syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not using any module bundler like webpack or etc.
You should assign you components to some javascript global object, because objects from .jsx are not put in global scope

So here is the solution (used **window** object here)

Defined module:

```
window.AdminMenu = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Menu</h1>
    );
  }
});
```

Where you use it:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <window.AdminMenu/>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: You said: **"If you are not using any module bundler like webpack or etc"**. Does **"etc"** in   
 include **"grunt"** I am using grunt to bundle my js. I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use

```
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
```

in place of

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use ES6 modules instead of require with React

export a module:

```
// src/hello.js
// export as default
export default const hello = ({name}) => (
  <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
)
```

import a module:

```
// src/index.js
// import from relative directory (src)
import Hello from './hello'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Hello name="Pavel" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: got an error on `const`: `browser.js:2027 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:15)`

Comment: without `const` getting an error: `VM1842:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Comment: definitely, because its not copy paste code, you should setup webpack to support es6

Comment: To get it up and running take a simple boilerplate, and check out what its doing... https://github.com/srn/react-webpack-boilerplate

Comment: Can someone help me :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466549/using-django-how-can-i-import-one-react-component-into-another

Answer (score 2):

You should read more about modules for example here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/

The main problems in your existing code are:

1. It looks, in spite of that you are using Webpack, you use it wrong way. In your final bundle (final JS file), it shouldn't contain any 'require' keywords. Did you use Babel with your webpack? Please, show us your WebPack config.
2. Your AdminMenu file looks not like module. Your adminMenu file should contain 'export' keyword, after that you will be able to 'require' or 'import' it from other files.

Also, you can write questions in comments with Russian if it is more convenient for you