# renderToString causes an Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

I am currently facing this issue for 3 days and unable to resolve:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (external "stream":1)
at n (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:10)
at n (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (server.node.js:4)
at n (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:3)
at n (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (renderer.js:2)
at n (bootstrap:19)
```

Basically, in my file renderer.js, I have this functionality:

```
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';

export default (req) => {
    let context = {};
    const content = renderToString(
        <Router location={req.path} context={context}>
            <FullPage />
        </Router>
    );
};
```

This is the main line which is causing the error basically, this happens when I try to import the renderToString method from 'react-dom/server':

[image]

I have tried out different things like removing target: 'node' but none of the solutions worked. What possible might be causing this? I have been stuck on this for the last 3 days and not sure what it is.

My Webpack configuration is:

webpack.base.config.js

```
module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            options: {
                presets: [
                    'react', 'stage-2',
                    ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] } }]
                ]
            },
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
}
```

};

webpack.server.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const SERVER_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/server');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config');

const config = {
    target: 'node',
    entry: SERVER_DIR + '/index.js',

    mode: 'production',
        output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.server.js'
    }
};


module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config);
```

Comment: Please include your Error as a Code Sample (`{}`) in your Question. [An image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: @LucaKiebel updated the question.

Comment: There are a few dozen questions regarding this error on Stack Overflow... For instance, [ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38219311/215552). Have you looked at any of those?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have looked into almost all of them but none solves my issue. If you look closely, my error is because of the renderToString function, not my code. That function comes with the package react-router, which I have no control of.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Pictures of exceptions are not helpful when working with .NET (as per the link you shared), because a lot of details are encapsulated within the exception object. My error message is pretty straight forward, no extra details, so an image would be fine too.