# Cannot import class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two react files as follows. They are in same folder. But it is not working.

***Game.js***

```
import { Board } from 'Board';

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And in ***Board.js***

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Test</div>
    );
  }
}
export { Board };
```

I have the following cdn in my project.

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dnd@2.4.0/dist/ReactDnD.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dnd-html5-backend@2.4.1/dist/ReactDnDHTML5Backend.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
```

I couldn't run the project because it shows an error

> react.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SxaP.png)

Comment: replace `export { Board };` with `export default Board` and import by  `import Board  from 'Board';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need require js when I use babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593694/do-i-need-require-js-when-i-use-babel)

Comment: `{}` is used when you are importing only some specific export, in your case you have created a separate file so definitely you are creating only one class Board

Comment: what build tool are u using?webpack or else?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I don't know if i am using any build tool. I am just using cdn and text editor

Answer (score 0):

Import `Board` like this.

```
import { Board } from './Board';
```

Or export component like this in `Board.js`.

```
export default Board ;
```

import like this in `Game.js`

```
import Board from './Board';
```

Comment: post some more log

Comment: add {} braces since you are exporting using export{}

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Check it

Comment: Where should i add braces?

Comment: in `board.js` you are exporting like this `export { Board };` that's why, 
if you are exporting like `export default Board ;` then no need of `{}`

Comment: in ES6 it is required to use {}?

Comment: i mean while importing, try my ans or it might be problem with your babel version which you are using.

Comment: I guess this should work as it is, like @AmruthLS says , chekc this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7zmwsa and still your facing this issue then the problem lies in your build tool

Comment: @Jayavel. Ya i tried changing import react and react dom from `index.js` and added respective cdn in `index.html`. It works. I am not using any other code. So how can i resolve the build tool issue ?

Comment: For a simple working demo, referring cdn and working in a single html is fine, in rear future you may transpile lots of files like es6 to es5. For that we use tools like webpack , babel, grunt, there will be problems if you missed something while configuring this

Answer (score 0):

In your **Board** component (Board.js), you can do something like this:

```
export class Board extends React.Component {
  // code 
}
```

In your **Game** component (Game.js), import it by doing:

```
import { Board } from './Board';
```

Comment: Are you using a bundler like Webpack? If not, see this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219311/reactjs-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: No. Is it required even while using cdn ?