# Reactjs console errors: 'Components object is deprectated' & 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, jsx, babeljs

I'm trying to use jsx with classes create a simple hello world program to print 'Hello world' in my browser(firefox).
I can get a single page [html with embedded jsx][1] to work. But not when I try to use classes.

I am receiving the following in my **console output**

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://fb .me/react-devtools
You might need to use a local HTTP server (instead of file://): https://fb .me/react-devtools-faq react-dom.development.js:21347:9
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]
babel.js:61389:2
You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/ babel.js:61666:4

The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed. index.html
ReferenceError: require is not defined[Learn More]

    <anonymous> file:///Users/Jacob/temp/index.html:5 
    run https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js:61531 
    check https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js:61597 
    loadScripts https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js:61624
    onreadystatechange https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js:61549
```

---

**jsx/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';

class NavBar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    Hello world
                </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NavBar />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
            <!--
            <script data-main="scripts/main" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script> #caused other errors
            -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type='text/babel' src='jsx/index.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>    
​
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this on Firefox? See [their bug on that issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=799961). The other error seems to be answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38219311/215552). Please do some searching on the error, along with your tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219311/reactjs-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I had seen that question, but I took another look at it. It looks like I still have the same errors with their solution.
I'm also trying to install and use webpack, which is adding another level of confusion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey So is the Components object actually deprecated? Is it just a but that using react with firefox produces? Should I still be using component? What can I replace it with if I shouldn't?

Comment: It's a bug in Firefox. The one I included a link to. You don't need to change anything, since it's only Firefox that has the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix in firefox for your problem would be to change your jsx/index.jsx to

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    Hello world
                </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NavBar />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

i.e remove `'import'`

Go through [this](https://babeljs.io/en/setup/) for babel usage with babel-standalone.

As you are using babel-standalone it would be best if you change your code to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
            <!--
            <script data-main="scripts/main" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script> #caused other errors
            -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type='text/babel'>
          class NavBar extends React.Component {  
             render() {
              return (
                    <div>
                        Hello world
                    </div>
                 );
             }
          }

          ReactDOM.render(<NavBar />, document.querySelector('#root'))
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but this is the code I have posted before my updates.
I found out that I can take my original code and if I remove the imports from the js file and change the 2 react scripts to     `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.7/dist/react.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.7/dist/react-dom.js"></script>` it'll work. So it looks like my code works in an older version of react but not this one. Do you know what's up with that?

Comment: I removed the update, so only my original code is posted

Comment: if you remove imports than it will work with version 16 too.

Comment: go to [this](https://babeljs.io/en/setup/) to see babel usage with babel-standalone

Comment: and remember if you use your way then later if you need to import other components then again you will get same error `ReferenceError: require is not defined` and also note babel-standalone has no support for modular code.[source](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/issues/71)

Comment: when you use `import` babel transpile it into `require` and require is not supported in the browser, and  you get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`