# Problem with import in small react example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and I have a problem : I have directly imported react.js, react-dom.js and babel.js in my index.html to test React (as described in the 'Add React to a Website' of the React doc website)

My index.html :

```
...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="src/index.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
.....
```

I have made a `index.js` file that call `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`
But this file does not know what is `App` which is defined in App.js

In App.js, I have this :

```
'use strict';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If, in my index.js, I try to import it like that `import App from './App.js';` (tried `import App from 'App.js'`, `import App from 'App'` too), I have this error :

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined[En savoir plus] index.html line 24 > scriptElement:3:5
    <anonyme> file:///media/jon/Projets/Projets/facturationJS/public/index.html line 24 > scriptElement:3
    i https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js:24
    r https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js:24
    o https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js:24
    onreadystatechange https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js:24
```

​Can anyone help my to understand how I can import/export my classes from different files ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: when you use `import` babel transpile it into `require` and `require` is not supported in the browser, and you get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`. you can go to  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045824/reactjs-console-errors-components-object-is-deprectated-referenceerror-re/55048272#55048272) for  solution of similar issue

Comment: As said, babel doesn't bundle your files together. You should use a bundler like webpack.

Comment: Since you are using babel-standalone. Go through [this](https://babeljs.io/en/setup/) for babel usage with babel-standalone. And also note that babel-standalone has no support for modular code [source](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/issues/71)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer !